# How to ORM filter a query with parameter list exactly?

Tags: python, django, orm

I have a query filter

```
query_1 = Model.objects.filter(param = param)
```

I need to filter this list to another ORM and return true or flase only if all the data in the query_1 is in the second query.
Like,

```
query_2 = AnotherModel.objects.filter(field__in=query_1)
```

return True only if all the objects in the query_1 list is in the query_2.

Comment: What is `field`, a `ManyToManyField`?

Comment: foriegnkey field

Comment: So exactly what is the semantics of the query? You want to know if the `AnotherModel` objects refer to all items in `query_1`? So then the result is `True`/`False`?

Comment: yes. True only if all the objects in query_1 is present in the AnotherModel.

Comment: Can you please share your `models.py`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it can be done using only ORM. If `field` is foreignkey to Model:

```
def my_func(param):
  list_of_ids_1 = Model.objects.filter(param = param).values_list('id', flat=True)
  list_of_ids_2 = AnotherModel.objects.filter(field__in=list_of_ids_1).values_list('field_id', flat=True).distinct()

  return len(list_of_ids_1) == len(list_of_ids_2)
```

Comment: I used this logic but instead of comparing length, I sorted the list with id and compared, which is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume `Model`, `AnotherModel` are like this

```
class Model(models.Model):
    param=models.CharField(...)
    ...

class AnotherModel(models.Model);
    field = models.ForeignKey(Model, on_delete=...)  
    ...
```

Then the following query will return only those `Model` which have corresponding `AnotherModel`

```
result = Model.objects.filter(param=param, anothermodel__isnull=False)
```

but if you want to check the `filter(param=param)` result if there is any model which is not present in `AnotherModel`, you have to do it manually

```py
exists = true
query_1 = Model.objects.filter(param = param)
for model in query_1:
    if not AnotherModel.objects.filter(field=model).exists():
        exists = false
        break

# if exists is true that means all of the query_1 obj is there in AnotherModel
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if there is any `Model` for which there is no `AnotherModel` with:

```
not Model.objects.filter(anothermodel=None).exists()
```

if the query returns `True` then `not …` will thus return `False` and this means that all `Model`s are referenced by `AnotherModel` and vice versa.